# What is the correct approach for integrating ReactJS with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot Rest API with ReactJS for frontend. What is the right way to achieve this in the following scenario?

As a Java backend developer for years, I've used JSF and related component libraries on frontend side. Now I'm struggling with picturing ReactJS and Spring Boot integration in my head. I have a number of RESTful Spring Boot Microservices at backend which are behind a proxy (Zuul to be exact & SSO & OAuth2 - JWT protected). My frontend app is going to consist of two parts. Landing page and an admin panel (dashboard). What is the correct way to integrate ReactJS and Spring Boot for this setup? I've seen two approaches. One involves in bundling two apps together and building them using Maven, making them talk on websocket, the other way consists of completely separating two applications.

Maven based approach that I encounter:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v10.11.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>webpack build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>webpack</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By following the above method, should I expect that my app is going to have a lot more capabilities by means of security or just calling the api with a token/api key will do fine as I've been already trying recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the frontend-maven-plugin plugin can be very helpful in building front-end applications via maven, I would segregate the front-end from your java application completely. Front-end applications have their own build configuration&tools, and forcing to build a front-end application using maven is a bit cumbersome IMHO.

Regarding security, I'd say there isn't much of a difference between both implementations, as in both scenarios the back-end responds with a 403 and the front-end will have to handle it. However, in your first option your java application may have control over whether to allow access to the static files initially. If you'd rather not send the static files on beforehand to unauthenticated users, a higher level access management tool such as [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) might be helpful.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to ask. Segregating front-end from back-end will also help if it is decided to switch to another front-end framework/library in the future.Will also look into Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property in pom.xml -->

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <frontendSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</frontendSrcDir>
        <node.version>v8.11.3</node.version>
        <npm.version>5.6.0</npm.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
```

Dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Build in pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>${frontendSrcDir}</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-frontend-tools</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>build-frontend</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>position-react-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/templates/yourdirectory</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${frontendSrcDir}/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

controller-->

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sample")
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping({"/",""})
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:/sample/default/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/default/**")
    public String catalogsListing() {
        return "shop/index.html";
    }
}
```

It works for me..

Refer : https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/